# How to recover mysql working prompt after accidentally typing an invalid slash command?

Tags: mysql

I made the mistake of trying to use postgres' `\d` to describe a table in mysql.

But in mysql `\.` runs a script by name "`source (\.) Execute an SQL script file. Takes a file name as an argument.`".

I don't know how to exit this state.  No amount of \c or ctrl-C seems to get me back to a state where I can run commands again.

```
mysql> \d tablename
mysql> show tables;
    -> \c
mysql> show tables;
    -> ^C
mysql> show tables;
    -> \q
Bye
```

More examples:

```
mysql> \d tablename
mysql> show databases;
    -> \x
    -> \c
mysql> \x
mysql> show databases;
    -> \r
Connection id:    274
Current database: *** NONE ***

mysql> show databases;
    ->
```

Comment: Have you tried to restart the service?

Comment: @Ramhound No need to restart the service itself. The OP could just kill the `mysql` client process from another shell.

Comment: @slhck - If they killed the service, wouldn't they have to start it again eventually, which is more or less a restart?

Comment: I don't want to kill the service over a simple typo.  I could of course \q quit and come back in, but I was hoping for a simpler solution if there was one.

Comment: @Ramhound You don't have to kill the *service* (`mysqld`), which also destroys any existing connections and could potentially cause issues in a shared environment. You can just kill the client window (`mysql`). Or exit the current shell and log back in.